# Postgresql: How to convert a timestamp column to a timestamp with time zone column at UTC?

Tags: postgresql, datetime

I have a `timestamp` column in my database that currently stores a time assumed to be in UTC. I would like to upgrade this column to a `timestamp with time zone` and have the timestamp stay the exact same regardless of what time zone the database is running under.

Our local system is running in UTC so a simple `alter table tab alter col type timestamp with time zone` works fine for us; but I want to make sure that any of our clients' systems can be upgraded as well and maintain the UTC timezone of the data even if they may be running in non-UTC on the system.

The documentation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) states to use AT TIME ZONE but doing that requires me to specify a time zone, and doing so seems to shift the date anyhow.

For example, if I have my time assumed to be UTC and I do `at time zone 'UTC-4:00'`, the timestamp then shifts from `2023-08-21 00:00:00.000000` to `2023-08-20 20:00:00.000000 +00:00`

How can I make it stay at `2023-08-21 00:00:00.000000 +00:00` regardless of the timezone of the system?

---

### **Edit for clarity:**

- My server is currently in UTC.
- My column is of type `timestamp without time zone`
- The data was inserted into the database "as" UTC
- I need to convert the column to `timestamp with time zone` so that queries return the correct time once shifted for local time.

  - I query the database from Java, so the `java.sql.Timestamp` that I get back from the database is assuming that the timestamp is actually `2023-08-21T00:00:00.000000-4:00` when I need it to be `2023-08-20T20:00:00.000000-4:00`.

When I execute the following statement as a test to see how it behaves, the data in the database gets shifted the "wrong" way.

```
alter table tab
    alter col type timestamp with time zone
using col at time zone 'UTC-4:00';
```

I would have expected the column to then contain the value `2023-08-21T04:00:00.000000Z` but it actually contains `2023-08-20T20:00:00.000000Z`, so when I read it out in Java, it goes back even further to `2023-08-20T16:00:00.000000-4:00`.

So what I'm asking is, how can I tell PostgreSQL what the data in the column *is* as opposed to what I want it to be? The statement `at time zone` seems to convert "to" the time zone, not "from" the time zone.

Comment: The data type `timestamp without time zone` does not adjust/account for difference time zones; `timestamp with time zone` does.  It seems that what you have is what you want.  If you need to change type then perhaps you to store as `at timezone utc` (do not assume it is utc) and subsequently retrieve (select) specifying `at timezone utc`. I would not consider changing the type from `timezone` to `timezonetz` as an upgrade, just a different data type with the corresponding different data semantics.

Comment: @Belayer I updated the question for more clarity.

Comment: @Mirrana it's actually a lot more confusing. UTC means `00:00`. A column `without time zone` will contain `2023-08-21T00:00:00.000000`, not `2023-08-21T00:00:00.000000-4:00`. And `00:00` at UTC, *really* is 20:00 in the previous date at UTC-4. That `-4` means 4 hours behind UTC. `when I read it out in Java,` how do you do that? It seems you're making *another* conversion to local time

Comment: Perhaps what you want is UTC*+4*? If the value is already at UTC, why not *leave* it in that timezone with  `using col at time zone 'UTC'`? `timestamp with time zone` comparisons always take the stored offset into account. The offset you used in the conversion doesn't affect any values stored in the future either. You can compare and sort such values no matter what offset they contain

Comment: A value entered into a `timestamptz` field will  be rotated to UTC using either the timezone/offset included in the value or in the absence of those the [TimeZone](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-TIMEZONE) setting. On retrieval the process will be reversed. Contrary to the name the time zone of the original value is not saved, so it cannot be recovered. You will need to deal with that on retrieval using `AT TIME ZONE` on the client end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I make it stay at 2023-08-21 00:00:00.000000 +00:00 regardless of the timezone of the system?

You can't.  The timestamptz will always be converted to the connection time zone upon the data being sent.  So unless the connection time zone is UTC or a synonym, it will not be sent with +00.  That is what timestamptz does.  If you don't want that, then don't use timestamptz.

If you had just done your ALTER TABLE command with AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', then the new thing sent to the client would be *equivalent to* '2023-08-21 00:00:00.000000+00', it would just be spelled in the way the client prefers its timestamptz values to be spelled, for example '2023-08-20 20:00:00-04' for me.

Comment: I updated the question with further clarification. Unless I'm misunderstanding what you're saying, it doesn't seem to behave that way.

Comment: This turns out to have been correct. I was very confused because it turns out that my client was in UTC no matter what the time zone of the server was. So after doing some testing on a scratch database in a different time zone, I was able to confirm that `alter col type timestamptz using col at time zone 'UTC'` correctly converts the column data without changing the intended value.